# Sketchup objects and Visio Stencils for master plan designing for my garden

Tags: design

This is the start of a long journey for me and hopefully it will end with a good looking garden. Short term objective: create the layout and select the plants. Long term...implement the above, so you will probably see lots of questions coming from me in the months to come

Here is the first: I have finished reading Residential Landscape Architecture by James E Hiss so now I have some good guidelines for proceeding with the design of our site. 
I am going to use Visio (for a master paln) and Sketchup for 3D simulation and rendering. 
Can anybody recomend any good Visio stencils and templates for Landscape Design? There is a Plants set of stencils but I am not happy with it all all. I think it should contain more that what it is included

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for off-site resources. Please see http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/634/do-we-really-want-questions-asking-for-off-site-resources for more information.

Comment: There is a similar question about what software is best to be used for design. How come that that one was allowed?

Comment: Here http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2536/what-are-some-good-landscape-design-planning-softwares

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That question predated the meta post where the policy was established.

Comment: Are you aware of [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange? You'd need to provide better requirements than "Can anybody recommend any good Visio stencils and templates for Landscape Design?". See http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information for what they look for in a question.

Comment: the sketchup community has a wide range of questions and templates  see here http://forums.sketchup.com/search?q=plants

Comment: I am a member of that community. My question is about Visio stencils and I prefer to get an answer from someone who is using the templates/stencils and not from someone who is creating them

Comment: I tried to find a way to comment but this looks like the only way.  This site is called gardening and landscaping and this question is completely on topic!  Allow this guy to show what he is doing!  Just the technical aspects of software IS NOT LANDSCAPING!!  Just because one purchases a software package does not a LANDSCAPE ARCHITECT MAKE!  They are asking pertinent questions on the correct site as far as I know...